# Entity Framework for .NET Core console application

Tags: c#, entity-framework, console-application

I am trying to develop a tool to migrate data from SQL databases to NoSQL database. The application need to be a console application. I wanted to use EntityFramework as the ORM framework. When i am trying to install the NuGET package the nuget package manager says that EF is not compatible with the console application.

Is there any way i can use EF6 with my console application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework 6 will not work on .NET Core ; it was built for .NET Framework, and would require serious restructuring to work on Core.

Instead, look at [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/#pivot=efcore)